# How to redirect to home page after SCLAlertView showWaiting alert?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, alert

I would like to show a SCLAlertView alert and after few seconds, it will disappear and redirect to other viewcontroller. But now what i did is after click on "Done" button, the action only can be executed. Any idea? Please help.

Here is my code:-

```
-(IBAction)submitButtonDidPressed:(id)sender {
 NSString *userName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome back %@", txtUsername.text];

            SCLAlertView *alert = [[SCLAlertView alloc] init];
            [alert addButton:@"Done" target:self selector:@selector(clickLogin:)];
            alert.customViewColor = ThemeBlueColor;
            [alert showWaiting:self title:@"Welcome" subTitle:userName closeButtonTitle:nil duration:2.0f ];
}

-(void) clickLogin:(UIButton*)sender
{
    int index = 0;
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = index;
    [self.tabBarController.viewControllers[index] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

}
```

Comment: Look into the `dismissBlock` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `alertIsDismissed`  to call navigation like this:

```
 -(IBAction)submitButtonDidPressed:(id)sender {
     NSString *userName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome back %@", txtUsername.text];

       SCLAlertView *alert = [[SCLAlertView alloc] init];
         [alert addButton:@"Done" target:self selector:@selector(clickLogin:)];
         alert.customViewColor = ThemeBlueColor;
         [alert showWaiting:self title:@"Welcome" subTitle:userName 
         closeButtonTitle:nil duration:3.0f ];


         [alert alertIsDismissed:^{
                  [self clickLogin:nil];
          }];

    }
```

Comment: Great, @Abdelahad, your solution is works! thanks alot!